# Show that there is a STS(n) if exist one 1-Error-Correcting Code.

Tags: combinatorics

STS(n) is  2-(n, 3, 1) design that every two elements appear in exact one block.
and the size of every block in STS(n) is 3.

if you are not familier with Error corectiong codes you could see also:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Error-CorrectingCode.html

Comment: I also know STS and error correcting as well but what is the relation between them?!....which leads to solve this problem